# Django LocaleMiddleware does not add slash with APPEND_SLASH enabled

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-i18n

I've encountered a problem using LocaleMiddleware in django 1.6.
It does not add extra slash event if **settings.APPEND_SLASH** is set to **True**. The text error text is:

> ```
> Request Method:   GET 
> Request URL:  http://pollina.ru/ua/add
> Django Version:   1.6.2 
> Exception Type:   DoesNotExist 
> Exception Value:   Poll matching query does not exist.
> Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py
> ```
>
> in get, line 307

As far as I understand the django engine does not event reach the LocaleMiddleware that appends slash to url. 
my urlconf looks like this

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^$',MainPage.as_view(),name="mainpage"),
    url(r'^add/$', PollCreator.as_view(),name="addpoll"),
    ..........
)
```

So how can I make django engine reach the LocaleMiddleware and make it rewrite url by appending extra slash to my url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is closed.
The problem was that other regexps that were defined after the:

```
    url(r'^add/$', PollCreator.as_view(),name="addpoll"),
```

matched that url but did not respond properly